# Rollup alias fails after moving to Rollup 3

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, rollupjs

So this is the part inside the `rollup.config.js` that worked fine under Rollup 2 an `rollup-plugin-import-alias` :

```
alias({
    Paths: {
        'myfuncs': './src/js/node_modules/mylib/src/js/myfuncs',
    },
}),
```

After updating to Rollup 3 and `@rollup/plugin-alias` I'm using this:

```
alias({
    entries: [
        { find: 'myfuncs', replacement: './src/js/node_modules/mylib/src/js/myfuncs' },
    ]
}),
```

and getting this:

> [!] Error: Could not load ./src/js/node_modules/mylib/src/js/myfuncs/
> (imported by ../../../../d:/Dropbox/src/js/components/staticfunc.js):
> EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read Error: Could not load
> ./src/js/node_modules/mylib/src/js/myfuncs/ (imported by
> ../../../../d:/Dropbox/src/js/components/staticfunc.js): EISDIR:
> illegal operation on a directory, read

The /src/js/ folder is a virtual folder lying in my Dropbox, but that did no trouble in Rollup 2.

Did I misunderstand something about `entries`? Because in the alias documentations, `Paths` are no longer found.

Comment: ChatGTP told me i should do this replacement: `./src/js/node_modules/mylib/src/js/myfuncs/index.js`. And it worked ...

Comment: The error was pretty clear but its good that it could help you in this instance.

Comment: Well if you are switching from the previous alias (used for some years), there is no indication the path can't be handeled that way anymore. happy it works.